# python count down to event, print line every minute

Tags: python

Would anyone have a better way to make a count down timer for a specific date and time in UTC time zone with the `datetime` library?

The script below works to count down to the `start_time` but I have something wrong in the while loop there is an if statement where I am trying to print every minute the duration remaining time left in minutes until the countdown ends, but the `%` is not working the way I thought it would, its just prints every millisecond or second the remaining. Any tips greatly appreciated on to write this better?...

```
from datetime import datetime,timezone
    
    
start_script = datetime(2022, 7, 9, 13, 50, tzinfo=timezone.utc)

def timer():

    while (start_script - datetime.now(timezone.utc)).total_seconds() >= 0:

        if (60 - (start_script - datetime.now(timezone.utc)).total_seconds() % 60):
            print("RUNNING IN MINUTES: ",((start_script - datetime.now(timezone.utc)).total_seconds() /60))

timer()

print("RUN MY SCRIPT NOW!!!")
```

Comment: The spin lock is a terribly inefficient implementation anyway. You'll want to change it to `time.sleep(60)` until you reach the scheduled time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```py
from datetime import datetime


def timer(countdown_to):
    last_minute = datetime.now().minute
    while datetime.now() <= countdown_to:
        if datetime.now().minute != last_minute:
            print('Time left:', int((countdown_to - datetime.now()).total_seconds() // 60), 'min')
            print('Time now:', datetime.now(), '\n') # Just for testing, you can remove if you want
            last_minute = datetime.now().minute


timer(datetime(2022, 7, 9, 14, 22))
```

I started running at 14:16:25, this is the output I got:

```
Time left: 5 min
Time now: 2022-07-09 14:17:00.000087 

Time left: 4 min
Time now: 2022-07-09 14:18:00.000073 

Time left: 3 min
Time now: 2022-07-09 14:19:00.000158 

Time left: 2 min
Time now: 2022-07-09 14:20:00.000077 

Time left: 1 min
Time now: 2022-07-09 14:21:00.000070 

Time left: 0 min
Time now: 2022-07-09 14:22:00.000326
```

Comment: Are you sure that locking out one of your CPUs is the ideal way to handle this?

Comment: It would still lock a CPU